# Screen record on Android 4.3 using adb

Tags: android, shell, terminal, adb

How can I record the screen on android 4.3 devices using adb shell.
in android 4.4 we can do using adb shell screenrecord /path/filename.mp4.

Comment: To those who want to do the same: just record with your phone's camera, period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but `screenrecord` [is only available on Android 4.4+ devices](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord).

Comment: so i cannot record the screen on 4.3 devices?

Comment: @user3334957: Not using the `screenrecord` added for Android 4.4. If your device is rooted, there are utilities available to do screen recordings. Or, if your device supports HDMI out, there are hardware HDMI recorders that you could investigate.

Comment: @user3334957: Not without some third-party software.

Comment: If anyone is feeling motivated, all of the pieces required for screen recording are present in Android 4.3.  Only one 4.4 API was used (`SurfaceComposerClient::destroyDisplay()`), and the command will work fine without it.